# Github action fails to fetch pub package from private repo

Tags: flutter, dart, github-actions

I have a flutter project which is fetching a package from a private repo on Github such as:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  my_package:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:username/my_package.git
      ref: main
```

When I run `flutter pub get` on my local computer, everything is fine since I have my computer connected to GitHub through ssh, but once I push on GitHub, the GitHub actions I have are failing to fetch the package with the message `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)`. I understand the error message, I wonder if there is a better way to do this and pass the action.

Here is the GitHub action script:

```yaml
name: Flutter

on: [pull_request, push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1.5.0

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: flutter packages get

      - name: Format
        run: flutter format --set-exit-if-changed lib test

      - name: Analyze
        run: flutter analyze lib test

      - name: Run tests
        run: flutter test --no-pub --coverage --test-randomize-ordering-seed random
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A "Permission denied" error means that the server rejected your connection.
GitHub Actions **only have access to the repository they run for.**

There are two ways to fetch this private package:

#### 1- Personal access tokens

The easy way is to create to new personal access token and fetch the library using that access token

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  private_package:
    git:
      url: https://username:token@github.com/user/repo
      ref: main
```

- ref is the branch name or commit id
- url example : https://Mdkhaki:ghp_LMWzHKnNctxxX9dmP4kxmnwjshRMmJ2MyjF8@github.com/Mdkhaki/private-package.git

#### 2- SSH-agent

So, in order to access additional private repositories, you need to create an SSH key with sufficient access privileges. To learn more [visit](https://github.com/webfactory/ssh-agent)

Comment: I used SSH-agent for security purposes and it worked for he. This answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Deploy keys](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys) feature from GitHub

It is very easy, powerful, and designed for use cases like that.

Steps:

1. Create an **SSH** key on your local machine with the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "git@github.com:username/repo.git"
```

**Notes:**

- Replace `username` with you GitHub username that owns the repository and replace `repo` with the repository name.
- Don't set a **passphrase** for the key or it will not work, just hit enter when you prompted for that.

You should see the output location of the generated key pair, it will be in form of two files, a public key file ends with `.pub` and a private key file without an extension.

2. In the private repository you want to use, go to `Settings` -> `Deploy keys` -> `Add Deploy key`, enter a title for the key (the title choice is up to you, it is used to easily identify the key later) and copy the content of the **public key** file and paste them in the key field.
3. For your GitHub Action, add a new **Secret** with the value of the contents of the **Private Key** file.
4. Use [webfactory/ssh-agent](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/webfactory-ssh-agent) action like the following:

```
- uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.9.0
  with:
    ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
```

**Note:** Replace `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` with the name of the secret that holds the value of the private key.

Tada , You have just used your private repository in your action in a secured way.